# How to Prevent Current Drain from an Android Phone's USB Connector?

Tags: power-supply, current, usb, diodes, android

Noob alert - I'm very much a hobbyist not a professional so doubtless fall into the 'little knowledge is a dangerous thing' category.

So... I have a project which requires simultaneous charging of an Android phone and a power bank. Pretty straightforward - essentially I have a Y cable whereby a micro B USB socket at the base of the Y connects to 2 micro B plugs, one plugs into the phone, the other to the power bank. Power applied to the socket flows to both devices and charges them. Works fine.

However when I unplug the external power to stop charging, the phone loses approx 10% power per hour compared to 4% if the phone is unplugged from the Y cable. I assumed that the power bank's charging input was draining current from the phone so tried the obvious solution (to me, at least) of inserting a rectifier diode into the +V line supplying the phone. However the phone wouldn't charge, presumably due to the voltage drop across the diode. So I then added a step up converter (1-5V input to 5V output) between the diode and the phone. This seems to work, in that the phone charges OK and the power loss when not charging is reduced to around 4%. However,

1. I'm sure this is terrible engineering practice and
2. the diode and step-up converter run extremely (dangerously?) hot when charging, even with a heatsink.

So all advice and better solutions for preventing the current drain would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The phone shouldn't be charging the power bank unless the phone is in OTG mode.

Comment: I wonder if the phone kept trying to negotiate a charging mode because the cable is non-standard charging cable, and is still connected to a device. Are both sides of the Y rated for data and charging? Is the Y splitter charging only?

Comment: @Passerby I agree, but I can't think of any other explanation for the fact that the rate of power loss is doubled when the phone is connected to the power bank - nothing else has changed

Comment: @Dmitri the Y splitter is charging only so I assume the phone can't negotiate a charging mode